# How to calculate the range from mean and SD?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, population

Is is possible to calculate or estimate the range of a population if I know the mean, population size and standard deviation?
I am doing a research and the mean age of the population is 29.9 +/- 5.3 SD, the population size is 21. What will be range of the population age?

Answer (score 6):

*When writing the lower part, I missed that the population size is 21. I somehow thought the question was for general population size. For known population size 21 there should be a mathematical maximum range, not only a minimum one. First now considerations regarding the maximum possible range:*

Note that it is possible to have a very small observation if all observations larger than the mean 29.9 are not much larger. Here is how to find the smallest possible observation. Let's say 20 observations have size $29.9+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ and one observation has size $\delta<29.9$. Then for the mean:
$$ 29.9=\frac{20*(29.9+\epsilon)+\delta}{21}\Rightarrow \delta=29.9-20\epsilon.$$
The variance is $5.3^2=28.9$, so
$$ \frac{20\epsilon^2+(\delta-29.9)^2}{21}=\frac{20\epsilon^2+(20\epsilon)^2}{21}=28.9, $$
thus
$$\frac{420\epsilon^2}{21}=20\epsilon^2=28.9\Rightarrow \epsilon=\sqrt{28.9/20}=1.202$$
and $\delta=29.9-20\epsilon=5.86$, so that's the smallest observation you can have, but only if it is the only observation smaller than the mean and all other observations are larger.

On the other hand, the same argument but assuming $\epsilon<0$ shows what can happen if 20 observations are smaller than the mean and only one is larger. Then we get $\epsilon=-1.202$, and $\delta=29.9-20\epsilon=53.94$, which is the biggest observation you can have, again only if all other observations are smaller than the mean.

*Now for unknown population size, this was the original answer:*

No, it's not. Technically any mean and SD are compatible with any range larger than a minimum possible range, which I haven't checked or computed, but for a given population size there is a minimum possible range.

But the range can be arbitrarily bigger than that. Note that a Gaussian distribution, which is normally taken as the basis for using mean and sd for estimation, is theoretically unlimited, i.e., it ranges (if infinitely many observations were available) from minus to plus infinity, which already shows that you can have an arbitrarily large range with any given mean and sd.

Obviously there are physical bounds in your real example, however in a general situation nothing can be said apart from that the range is larger or equal to the minimum possible one.

Comment: The population is of size 21, so most of your remarks don't look appropriate for this situation.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I somehow missed that. Answer edited.

Comment: ...and edited again, now hopefully correctly figuring out what the most extreme possibilities are.

Comment: Well done--but because you changed "29.9" to "28.9" partway through the calculations, your endpoints are off a little bit.

Comment: I hoped I have only used $28.9=5.3^2$, the variance?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that.  What triggered my comment was a slight difference between your result and the Chebyshev Inequality calculation; I was hunting for an explanation.

Comment: Obviously Chebyshev's is an inequality and doesn't need to hold precisely. I think the difference comes from the fact that Chebyshev in the proof doesn't use that if you have $n$ points (i.e., a CDF that has minimum 1/n jumps) the smallest amount of probability mass that can be on one side of the mean is 1/n.

Comment: Chebyshev's Inequality *does* hold precisely in extreme cases: it's a sharp inequality.

Answer (score 0):

[Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) gives bounds for how much probability mass can be more than a certain number of standard deviations from the mean: no more than $\frac 1 {k^2}$ of a distribution's values can be more than $k$ standard deviations away from the mean. So, for instance, there are no distributions with more than 1% of their probability mass more than 10 standard deviations from the mean.  This is an upper bound, and it's possible for there to be less. We cannot, however, say that there is some point at which there is no further probability mass; the normal distribution, for instance, has probability mass arbitrarily far from the mean.

Comment: In the present case we definitely *can* say much more, because of the assumption this is a finite population of $n=21$ subjects. Thus, the limits are $29.9\pm\sqrt{21}\times5.3=\{54.2,5.6\},$ consistent with the analysis in the first answer by @Lewian.